# How to run my java project on any system with JDBC that only works on my system as of now?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, netbeans

I'm building a miniature brewing system using Java in Netbeans IDE. In order for my program to use and store data, I have constructed a database under Netbeans services tabs.

[image: My database and its driver under services tab.]

My java code has no errors. I have used the following code to connect my java program with my database...

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/BrewingDatabase", "userID", "password");
```

Once I cleaned and built my project, it worked perfectly on my computer without any exceptions or errors caught. However, when I copy my project folder and run it on another computer, my program fails to connect with the database. I just started coding recently, and I am unaware of how to solve a problem of such sort.

How do I make my program runnable on any PC?

Comment: Do you get any error messages when trying to connect?

Comment: @MonopoleMagnet I am getting an exception thrown at me.

Comment: What is the exception? Is there a message to go with it?

Another thing we could try: Try to post a minimum version of your project somewhere, I can try to run it locally and see what Netbeans says for me

Comment: @MonopoleMagnet  I talked to a few people and they told that the issue is that my connection code tries to connect to localhost and when I run it on another system, it is unable to find the database file there. How to I get the program to know the directory of the database files if I copy it into the project folder once cleaned and built?